# Is this possible to swipe between versions on Git - just like branches?

Tags: git

I want to develop a REST API. In order to do this, I have to split this API for versions. In such a case, app1 which is based on API v1 will not get hurt when I release API v2.
Later on I can release an update for app1 to be app2 which is based on v2 of the API.

Sound good. I can use URL endpoints in order to serve those requests respectively to their versions. Even when asking without specifying a version, the latest will be the default.

However, the same functions, or look alike functions will be on the same code, for example:

```
app.get("/users/:id", handlerOnV1());
app.get("/users/:id", handlerOnV2());
app.get("/users/:id", handlerOnV3());
...
```

And in the directories hierarchy will be something like this:

```
handlerV1.js
handlerv2.js
handlerv3.js
...
```

This is not the perfect thing, probably..

How can it be solved with Git?

Comment: I don't know what Git has to do with REST APIs, but yes, you can certainly maintain separate branches for the various versions of your API.

Comment: But I dont want tons of branches, like:
v1-feature-a, v2-feature-a v3-feature-a...

Comment: Well, you can always just maintain separate endpoints within the same branch.

Comment: And just have many versions directories in the code?

Comment: Imagining doing this from Java, you might just need a single folder.  Each class in that folder could be a certain version REST endpoint.  It really depends on your situation.